# Apply a list of functions in specific order

Tags: scala, functional-programming, combinatorics

I have some functions that represent choices, each choice having a distinct desirability. Consider

```scala
f1 : Seq[A] => Seq[A]
f2 : Seq[A] => Seq[A]
f3 : Seq[A] => Seq[A]
```

where `f1` is more desirable than `f2`, and `f3` is least desirable. I wrote this scala code to generate the results of making 2 consecutive choices, ordered from most desirable to least

```scala
def applyTwice[A](initial: Seq[A],
  f1: Seq[A] => Seq[A],
  f2: Seq[A] => Seq[A],
  f3: Seq[A] => Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {

  lazy val f1s = f1(initial).toStream
  lazy val f2s = f2(initial).toStream
  lazy val f3s = f3(initial).toStream

  f1(f1s) ++
    f2(f1s) ++ f1(f2s) ++
    f2(f2s) ++
    f1(f3s) ++ f3(f1s) ++
    f2(f3s) ++ f3(f2s) ++
    f3(f3s)
}
```

In general, a series of function applications is ranked by the worst function in the series. If the worst is a tie, compare the 2nd worst, and so on. For example, `f4(f1(a))` would be worse than `f3(f3(a))` because `f4` is worse than `f3`. Note that it is a tie between `f3(f2(a))` and `f2(f3(a))`.

I probably could generalize this to a variable number of functions, and (with more difficulty) a variable number of applications, but this seems like a classic problem that I just don't know the name of yet. Is this already built into some language/library? Is there a better way?

Comment: What does f1.. fn do?

Comment: @Shrey, do you mean with regard to the problem domain? It's hard to explain and I don't think it's relevant. At it's core, the problem is about placing items into locations, but there are business rules which make certain placements better than others.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it's a well-known thing, but it's pretty easy to generalise:

```
import scala.math.max
case class Fun[A](cost : Int, fun : Seq[A] => Seq[A])

def applyN[A](funs : Seq[Fun[A]], n : Int, initial : Seq[A]) = 
  (Seq((0, initial)) /: (1 to n)) { 
    case (acc, _) => for {
      f <- funs
      (cost, old) <- acc
    } yield (max(cost, f.cost), f.fun(old))
}
```

> scala> val funs = Seq(Fun[Int](2, _.map(_*2)), Fun[Int](3, _.map(_*3)))
>
> funs: Seq[Fun[Int]] = List(Fun(2,), Fun(3,))
>
> scala> applyN(funs, 2, Seq(1,2,3,4))
>
> res0: Seq[(Int, Seq[Int])] = List((2,List(4, 8, 12, 16)), (3,List(6, 12, 18, 24)), (3,List(6, 12, 18, 24)), (3,List(9, 18, 27, 36)))

Edit: I notice I've used a simplified cost function here, which just looks at the max, but you could easily collect the list of costs and apply whatever decision you wanted to them instead.

Comment: This is good, but I didn't mention that laziness is kind of important here - I want to avoid calling `f3` at all if a solution exists in `f2(f2(a))`. I think I can modify your code to do that, in which case the `cost` becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I see what you mean. One approach in that case is to simply build the function combinations in a similar way before applying them to initial, in which case you can just do something similar to 'find' on a view to get the first matching solution. You can compose functions with `f.compose(g)` for f(g(\_)) or `f.andThen(g)` for g(f(\_)).